# visual studio extension for #define removing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I use #define to shorten repeated code. For example

```
#define FOR(i, size) for (int i = 0; i < (int)(size); i++)
```

And then I have this code

```
FOR(i, 5)
```

Let's say I want to start from i = 1 and therefore i have to use classic for. Is there any estension to visual studio 2010 that would automatically change my code based on used #define to proper code which I can then modify to start from 1?

expected result of extension usage on above shown code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)(5); i++)
```

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't abuse the preprocessor like this. Readability is **way** more important than shortness.

Comment: sometimes #define'd code is more readable or maybe I want to remove unreadable #define from codes